# Read pkgversion from source

Tags: c++, c, gcc, cross-compiling

I'm using the blackfin toolchain with gcc for a project I'm working on. I have to switch the toolchain for different applications on different platforms. The name of this toolchain is defined with the --with-pkgversion flag. I want to generate a compile error when the application is being build with the incorrect toolchain based on this version information. Is there a define that describes this?`__VERSION__` returns no more then the bare version number (4.3.5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `gcc -E -dM src.c`.
This will give you a list of all macros defined. If what you want exists, it will be there.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, didn't know that one. I'm afraid that what I want doesn't exist then.